# Is every hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ determined by a unique normal vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthonormal

Is every hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ determined by a unique normal vector? And why?

I analysed for $\mathbb{R}$,  a hiperplane in $\mathbb{R}$ is a point, so the hyperplane is $PX= \alpha$, with $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. So $X=\alpha  / P$.

Comment: The normal vector isn't *unique*.  But the span of any normal vector will be the same one-dimensional subspace.  To prove this you use that theorem that says that you can always complete a basis of a subspace to a basis of the ambient space.  Then you just prove that any such extension for a basis of your hyperplane will be made by adding a vector determined up to scalar multiplication (you can do this part by proof by contradiction).

Comment: If you choose a *unit* normal vector it's *almost* unique-choosing the sign requires some additional information, namely, an *orientation*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider $\mathbb{R}^3$, and the (hyper)planes $x = 0$ and $x = 1$. Both have $[c, 0, 0]$ as normal vectors for all $c \neq 0$. So they are neither determined by their normal vectors, nor is their normal vector unique.

Note that these vectors comprise all their normal vectors, so there does not exist a normal vector which can distinguish these two planes.

Comment: I think what OP is asking is a bit different from what you have answered. OP wants: Given a hyperplane does there exist a unique vector to identify that hyperplane. Your answer: given a vector you can have many planes associated with it. They are not the same thing.

Comment: @AnuragA Good call, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @JohnColanduoni