# Does every hyperplane have a unique normal vector (up to non-zero scalar multiplication)?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am able to prove that the conjecture below is true in the $\mathbb{R}^3$ case, but I was wondering if the general case is true and if it is, how we might (nicely) prove it.

**Conjecture.** *Suppose $p$ is a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then $p$ has a normal vector and moreover, this normal vector is unique (up to non-zero scalar multiplication).*

---

My definitions:

**Definition 1.** Given $\mathbf{x}=\left(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\right)$ and $\mathbf{y}=\left(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n\right)$, we define: $$\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{y}=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i.$$

**Definition 2.** A *hyperplane* in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is any set of points that can be written as $$\left\{ \mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}:\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{x}=c\right\},$$ for some $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus\left\{ \mathbf{0}\right\} $ and some $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

**Definition 3.** We say that $\mathbf{b}=\left(b_{1},b_{2},\dots,b_{n}\right)\neq\mathbf{0}$ is a *normal vector* of the plane $p$  if: $$\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in p \implies \mathbf{b}\cdot\left(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\right)=0.$$

[Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537773/is-every-hyperplane-in-mathbbrn-determined-by-a-unique-normal-vector).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, yes.

In fact your "definition 2" gives $\mathbf a$ as the coefficients of the equation of a hyperplane as a nonzero vector, and this nonzero vector is a *normal* to that hyperplane as called for in "definition 3".

The algebra to prove this is very easy.  Write down the equations, satisfied by $x$ and $y$ of the hyperplane respectively, and take the difference.  We immediately have $\mathbf a \cdot (x-y) = 0$ as the constant $c$ cancels.

The argument goes the other way, to show that when $\mathbf b$ in "definition 3" is given, it also serves as a set of coefficients $\mathbf a$ in "definition 2".  That is, suppose a hyperplane $p$ has a normal vector $b$ as described above, and fix some point $y$ in that hyperplane:

$$ \mathbf b \cdot (x-y) = 0 \; \text{ for any } x\in p$$

Expanding the above gives $\mathbf b \cdot x = \mathbf b \cdot y$, and now that $y$ is fixed we get an equation of the form in "definition 2" where constant $c = \mathbf b \cdot y$:

$$ \mathbf b \cdot x = c $$

Therefore any $\mathbf a$ that defines the hyperplane equation in "definition 2" will serve as the normal vector $\mathbf b$ defined in "definition 3", and any normal vector $\mathbf b$ that satisfies "definition 3" will serve as the vector of coefficients $\mathbf a$ in "definition 2".  As a result these quantities have the same *uniqueness* property, namely that they are unique only up to taking a nonzero scalar multiple of a vector.

---

There seems to be a lesson here about *rank* or *dimension of a subspace*.  The normal vector to a *hyperplane* is unique (up to a nonzero scalar multiple) in $\mathbb R^n$ because the hyperplane is an $n-1$ dimensional thing, and this leaves only one dimension for things to be perpendicular to this.

So the uniqueness you want to show depends on making use of the $n-1$ dimensional nature of the hyperplane.  The easiest way to discuss this depends to a great extent on your background in linear algebra.

From the perspective of the one linear equation $\mathbf a \cdot x = c$, we see that the matrix form of this equation has a coefficient matrix of rank one (because $\mathbf a$ is nonzero).  Therefore the solutions to this equation (via the principle of superposition) consist of a *particular* solution to the inhomogenous equation plus all solutions of the *homogenous* equation $\mathbf a \cdot x = 0$.  Thus we have an $n-1$ dimensional "affine variety" of solutions.

But let's consider the uniqueness strictly from the perspective of the normal vector.  To simplify things, the normal vectors to the hyperplane $\mathbf a \cdot x = c$ are exactly the same as the normal vectors to the *subspace* $\mathbf a \cdot x = 0$.  This subspace has a basis of $n-1$ linearly independent vectors.  There is a one dimensional subspace *orthogonal* to these, (orthogonal is another word for perpendicular or *normal*), and that subspace is generated by vector $\mathbf a$.

Taken together the basis for the subspace $\mathbf a \cdot x = 0$ and the normal vector $\mathbf a$ give us a basis for all of $\mathbb R^n$.  The latter (because it is generated by one vector) is one dimensional, and the former is $n-1$ dimensional (so that the dimension of $\mathbb R^n$ is $n$ as we know).

This is a special case of the [Rank-Nullity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), which says the dimension of the *row space* of the coefficient matrix of the linear "system" $\mathbf a \cdot x = 0$ plus the dimension of the nullspace (the solutions/points of the hyperplane $\mathbf a \cdot x = 0$) is equal to the dimension $n$ of the domain $\mathbb R^n$.

Now the statement that all the nonzero normal vectors to the hyperplane are related by $\mathbf b = k\mathbf a$ for nonzero scalars $k$ is exactly the proposition that the subspace generated by one of these normal vectors is one dimensional.  In other words Span($\mathbf b$) = Span($\mathbf a$) forces $\mathbf b$ to be a nonzero multiple of $\mathbf a$ and vice versa.

Comment: What about uniqueness?

Comment: As you've pointed out, the normal vector $\mathbf b$ is only unique up to taking a nonzero multiple, and the same sort of thing is true for the coefficients $\mathbf a$ in the hyperplane equation (unique up to taking a nonzero multiple, since this is a single linear equation and multiplying both $\mathbf a$ and $c$ by a nonzero scalar is an elementary row operation in Gauss elimination).  I'll add a bit to my Answer to point out $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ have this same kind of *uniqueness* as a result of their interchangeable definitions.

Comment: I think what you've shown is this: Given any $\mathbf{b}$ that is a normal vector for the plane $p=\left\{ \mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}:\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{x}=c\right\}$, we can also express the plane as $p=\left\{ \mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}:\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{x}=d\right\}$ where $d\in\mathbb{R}$ is some constant. I'm can't quite see though how this also proves that $\mathbf{b}=k\mathbf{a}$ for some $k\neq0$.

Comment: Recall that I also showed that if you have a hyperplane $\mathbf a\cdot x = c$, then $\mathbf a$ is a normal vector to that hyperplane.  So the issue is simply whether $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ are both normal vectors to the hyperplane, then $\mathbf b = k\mathbf a$ for some $k\neq 0$.  This is the sort of "uniqueness" you mentioned several times, right?

Comment: Yes. And so, here is the proposition to be proven: "If $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are both normal vectors to a hyperplane, then there exists $k\neq0$ such that $\mathbf{a}=k\mathbf{b}$." I'm not sure where or how you've proven this proposition.

Comment: Note that if we ask about normal vectors to a variety *smaller* than a hyperplane, the uniqueness of that normal vector (even up to nonzero scalar multiples) fails.  For example, consider a line in three dimensional space.  The line is a one dimensional variety, and points on that line have perpendicular directions spanning two dimensions.  So the key here is that a *hyperplane* has an $n-1$ dimensional nature in $\mathbb R^n$.  I've added some material to my Answer about this, which you may well have seen in a course on linear algebra (dimension = size of a basis).